# Question related to SQL Server Driver support for pyodbc's fast_executemany option

Tags: python, pyodbc, executemany, odbc-sql-server-driver

I am trying to improve insert performance to a SQL Server Database table using Python. (First step taken is instead of row by row insert, prepare a bulk statement.)

After going through driver support documentation ( https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Driver-support-for-fast_executemany ), four of the below mentioned drivers deliver the same performance.

SQL Server Native Client 11.0
ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
SQL Server

Could someone please clear my doubt - why it could be so?

Kind regards,

Manoj.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post here. The drivers are: "SQL Server Native Client 11.0", "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server", "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" and "SQL Server".

Comment: As far as I know, all versions of Microsoft's ODBC driver for SQL Server support `fast_executemany`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GordThompson. I now feel that for rows like 120,000 it throws memory error if I use "SQL Server" driver.